# The sum of linear non-Hermitian operators can be Hermitian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, mathematics

It is easy to find that the sum of non-linear operators can be Hermitian, but I just wonder if there is any example that the sum of linear but not Hermitian operators could be Hermitian.

Answer (score 10):

Let $A$ be a linear and non-Hermitian operator. Then $B=A+A^\dagger$ is Hermitian.

Comment: I've added that $A$ is supposed to be linear (just because OP is asking for exactly that). Feel free to undo if you think it is not necessary.

Comment: Operators on a vector space are usually assumed to be  linear. Do you have an example of a  "non-linear opertor" in mind?

Comment: @mikestone Any anti-linear operator. That being said, the OP writes: *sum of non-linear operators can be Hermitian* - I've never thought about that, but it seems important for them that an answer considers linear operators.

Comment: @TobiasFünke Thanks! I agree with adding that; I was thinking about it implicitly because the OP said they were interested in linear operators, but doesn't hurt to state it explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

$\hat L_x=\frac12\left(\hat{L}_++\hat{L}_-\right)$ or $\hat x=\lambda({\hat{a}} +{\hat a}^\dagger)$ are obvious examples.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\sigma_+=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}, \sigma_-=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\\\sigma_x=\sigma_-+\sigma_+=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Where is this different from the answer of @ZeroTheHero?

Comment: @TobiasFünke It is a different example. But both answers fit the prescription given by Andrew: $B=A+A^\dagger$.